# Unitils EasyMock and JUnit @Rule from JUnit 4.10 to 4.11

Tags: easymock, temporary-directory, junit-rule, unitils

I have the Problem that when I use the `@Rule`Annotation from JUnit for my `TemporaryFolder` and want to use `Mock`s from `unitils.easymock` at the same time I get an `IlleagalStateException` in `JUnit` 4.11, whereas in `JUnit` 4.10 it still works.

So the following test runs under JUnit 4.10 and throws the `IllegalStateException` in 4.11:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4;

public class MyTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws IOException {
        File newFile = temporaryFolder.newFile();
    }

}
```

Even if I use the Annotation for the Mocking capability instead of `extends UnitilsJUnit4` it doesn't work in JUnit 4.11:

```
@RunWith(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
 ...
}
```

The error message when testing this code is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: the temporary folder has not yet been created
```

Something new I just additionally found out: In JUnit 4.10 I can also enforce the same error when passing a String in the `newFile()` call:

```
        File newFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("");
```

My question:

What is the proper way to make `TemporaryFolders` or `@Rule`s in general work together with `unitils.easymock.annotation.Mock`s in JUnit 4.11?

Or is Mocking with the easymock `@Mock` annotation and `@Rule`s at the same time simply not possible?

Versions:

```
easymock 3.4
unitils 3.4.3
```

Comment: I would suspect a problem in delegating between rules. Can you provide a fully failing unit test?

Comment: @Henri Thanks for your reply! I just edited the question (see edit comment for details). Hopefully that makes the error reproducable.